# Form issues with dynamically added input[] fields

Tags: jquery, input, addition, brackets, square-bracket

I have a script that successfully adds input fields based on a users selection.

For example

```
<input name=test[] value="1">
<input name=test[] value="2">
```

However, when the form is submitted these values (array) do not show up in the post.

If I add them to the html it works so is clearly a result of the html having been added to the DOM by javascript.

I have also tried $('name[coupon]').serialize().replace('%5B%5D', '[]'); on submit (where coupon is the name of the form) - but no joy!

Any advice please?

Comment: Do each of these dynamically added input controls have unique names? Per HTML specification, the value of a form input control will not be posted to the server if it does not have a name.

Comment: Yes - they have names as shown in the code example above. The issue seems to be the fact that I am adding names with square brackets at the end.... if I remove these all is OK - but that of course remove the array capability......

Comment: You should add quotes around the name - but it also works without them. The problem must be somewhere else. Perhaps paste the complete code.

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Hi - my earlier observation was wrong - it is not working without square brackets either!

Below is the DOM AFTER I have added code

    <input value="1" name="test[]">
    <input value="2" name="test[]">
    <input value="1" name="test1">

When I post the input fields with test[] are picked up - these were part of the hard coded html.

The input field with test1 (which was added by jquery) is not picked up.

If I add another input field with test[] I only see the origional two at the POST stage

Comment: OK - from another post I have found a solution - though not sure why!

IF I append the new html to the form rather than a div within the form it works!

Comment: That shouldn't matter *if* you are appending it correctly. You didn't post enough *clear* information about your specific problem.